# Working with classes and positioning

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

If I load myShip onto the game layer the joystick control works fine

**E.G**

```
  myShip = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship.png"];
  [myShip setScale:0.5];
  myShip.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),    CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
[self addChild:myShip];
```

**(I was doing this to test the controller code, with the thought later to make a shipClass and then add that to the layer and use the controller to control the shipClass position**
but the ShipClass when using this code then sits a 0,0 and wont move with the controls, what am I doing wrong?.

```
myShipshipClass = [[ShipClass alloc]initWith:self];
```

It's the first time I've started working with classes so I know its something im missing...

Conceptually I must be doing something wrong...
I'd love to know why the position gets changed and no longer works with the controller, and how to fix it so it can work.

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

[myMeteor updateMeteor:.02];


// Shoot bullets every half second
if ( currentTime - lastUpdate >= 0.5 ){
    [self shootBullet];
    lastUpdate = currentTime;
}

if ( moveJoystick.isMoving )
{
    NSLog(@" if update:moveJoystick.isMoving");
    CGPoint adjustedSpritePosition
    = CGPointMake(self.myShip02.position.x + moveJoystick.moveSize.width,
                  self.myShip02.position.y + moveJoystick.moveSize.height);

    if ( adjustedSpritePosition.x < 0 ){
        adjustedSpritePosition.x = 0;
    } else if ( adjustedSpritePosition.x > self.size.width ){
        adjustedSpritePosition.x = self.size.width;
    }
    if ( adjustedSpritePosition.y < 0 ){
        adjustedSpritePosition.y = 0;
    } else if ( adjustedSpritePosition.y > self.size.height ){
        adjustedSpritePosition.y = self.size.height;
    }

    myShip02.position = adjustedSpritePosition;
}
```

}

**//ShipCLass**

**this is what I changed and learnt to get the class to work**

```
- (instancetype)initWithImageNamed:(NSString *)name
{
    if (self = [super initWithImageNamed:name]) {
      //numOfDamages = 0;
      //numOfBullets = 100;
    }
    return self;
}
```

**//ShipCLass.h**

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "GameScene.h"
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

@class SpriteBar;
@interface ShipClass : SKSpriteNode <UIAccelerometerDelegate,SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
{
   GameScene *layer;

    //health
    int numOfDamages;

    //bullets
    int numOfBullets;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) SKNode *shipShield;
@property (nonatomic, retain) SKPhysicsBody *body;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int numOfDamages;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int numOfBullets;

-(id)initWith:(GameScene *)gameLayer;
@property(strong) SKTextureAtlas *atlas;

@end
```

**//ShootBullet**

```
    -(void)shootBullet{
   SKSpriteNode *bullet = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bullet"];
    bullet.position = myShip02.position;
    [self addChild:bullet];

CGPoint movePoint = [self destPointForAngle:shootJoystick.angle];
CGPoint adjustedPoint = CGPointMake(myShip02.position.x + movePoint.x, myShip02.position.y + movePoint.y);

SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveTo:adjustedPoint duration:1];
SKAction *removeAction = [SKAction removeFromParent];
[bullet runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[moveAction, removeAction]]];
```

}

//2 problems, the bullet node added to the ship on the gamelayer
now only the bullet node is visible (ship coordinates must be wrong or the relation of the node to the shipClass is wrong?)

Bullet nod position does not equal the ship position

Comment: You're changing the position of `myShip` not `myShip02`?

Comment: sadly no - If I replace the code and use ship02 - then the ship will sit at 0,0
I just wanted to post the code up so people can see how im changing ship position (my ship is just a sprite loaded onto the game layer - ship02 is a ShipClass)

Comment: I suggest you post the code for `initWith`.

Comment: Having the sprite hold a reference to the layer is very unusual and having it add itself to that layer when it's created is even more unusual.  I would simplify this relationship as it's somewhat insidious.

Comment: If `ShipClass` is a subclass of `SKSpriteNode`, replace `Ship = ...` with `self.texture = LEVEL01_TEX_SHIP;` and add `self` to the scene instead of `Ship`.

Comment: Sorry, its easier to learn by example.
How should the class look like exactly (I've only done this because it seems to work, but very happy to learn a better way :)

Comment: thanks  0x141E I will try this :)

Comment: Thank you some progress (self.texture = LEVEL01_TEX_SHIP) that made a lot more sense! - a mini eureka moment :P (so I suppose... I would now add physics body etc to "self" and any other changes I want reflected on my class, so that seems to make sense! )

problems, the bullet node (added in shootBullet method)
now only the bullet node is visible (ship coordinates must be wrong or the relation of the node to the shipClass is wrong?)

Bullet node position does not equal the ship position

all changes are reflected in the code

Comment: thank-you both especially 0x141E, after a bit more digging I changed my Class, and it now loads fine (am so happy!), thanks for the advice it helped me see eventually what I was doing wrong.
 
//now ship loads
 myShip02 = [[ShipClass alloc]initWithImageNamed:@"Ship"];
 [self addChild:self.myShip02];

Comment: Also code above reflects change in init

Comment: The `if` statement in ShipClass.m should be `if (self = [super initWithImageNamed:name]) {` not `if (self == ...`.

Comment: Yes you right, I sourced it from here (a typo I guess) :http://www.raywenderlich.com/62049/sprite-kit-tutorial-make-platform-game-like-super-mario-brothers-part-1 
in Player.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after a few members were kind enough to give a few good hints how to get the class to work. - Code for the solution

```
**//.h**

@interface ShipClass : SKSpriteNode 
{
    //extra cool stuff here 
}

- (instancetype)initWithImageNamed:(NSString *)name

@end
```

---

```
**.m**
- (instancetype)initWithImageNamed:(NSString *)name
{
    if (self = [super initWithImageNamed:name]) {
      //cool stuff here
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Doing this fixed the coordinate problem and simplified the whole process of making a class.** with less code to write, thanks guys!